# Android - User's Location

Tags: android, gps, location

I have been having issues with retrieving the user's location in my application. I used the code suggested by the official documentation, that is, I used

```
mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                mGoogleApiClient);
```

to get the last known location.
For some reason, getLastLocation returns null at every execution. I did add the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in my manifest.
Others seem to have the same problem, yet I couldn't get a clear solution.
I see no reason why this wouldn't work. 
Could it be due to the fact I am using an emulator to test the app?
If not is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented the Google Location api a few days ago and is working fine.
Since you haven't shown any code i'll tell you how i have set my app to use the api, hopefully that will help you.

I'm using android studio.In my **Project's gradle** i have added the following dependency:
    `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'`(Be sure you update this version number each time Google Play services is updated.)

In my **Module's gradle** i have added the following dependency:
    `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'`(Be sure you update this version number each time Google Play services is updated.)

**manifest.xml**

```
<manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
...
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/android_api_key"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    <activity
...
```

**strings.xml**
You need an android api key(see 2nd meta-data tag in manifest) from [google developers console](https://console.developers.google.com)

`<string name="android_api_key">putyourapikeyhere</string>`

**Activity or Fragment**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
```

In the activity's onCreate build your GoogleApiClient:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

If you use it in a fragment build it in it's onCreate:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();
mGoogleApiClient.connect();
```

the difference is in the input argument of GoogleApiClient.Builder.

Next you have to implement the callbacks

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    lat = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient).getLatitude();
    lng = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient).getLongitude();
}
@Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
}
@Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
}
```